# add a default flag to clang++ or g++

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

I'm trying to use clang++ or g++ to compile c++11 code by default, which means I want to omit "-std=c++11" flag when calling g++. Is there a clean way to do this?

`g++ source.cc` instead of `g++ -std=c++11 source.cc`

Thanks!

Comment: Makefiles, build scripts, shell scripts, shell aliases, cmake, qmake, autotools, ..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got some options:

- make a [Makefile](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Makefile)
- use an bash alias:

  ```
  alias g++="g++ -std=c++11"
  alias clang++="clang++ -std=c++11"
  ```